# Unable to login User credentials -Eucalyptus

Tags: console, centos, cloud, credentials, eucalyptus

We are trying to download user credentials by entering into Eucalyptus management console but couldn't do so.As we are entering USERNAME and PASSWORD as admin into the management console ,its not accepting it and showing the error "Invalid user/account name and/or password". All the ports are Listening. So please anyone tell what valid data to give input for Account name, username and password.Thanks in advance.[Unable to login Eucalyptus management console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MONm.png)

Answer (score 1):

You would have entered password during eucalyptus installation. The default is eucalptus, admin and password. You will have the credentials at eucarc file too. Hope it helps !!